# How to replace 3rd hyphen with empty space and 4th hyphen with colon in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
"2017-12-31-19-40" // Date Format
```

I have date format like above. I want to convert this string to proper date format like

```
"2017-12-31 19:40"
```

I tried like this:

```
var str = "2017-12-31-19-40";
var newStr = str.indexOf("-");
var newStr2 = str.indexOf("-", newStr+4)
var newStr3 = str[newStr2].replace(" ");
alert(newStr3);
```

But it giving me only hyphen. how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex replacement is a good option here:

```js
var input = "2017-12-31-19-40";
console.log(input);
input = input.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$1 $2:$3");
console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

The clean way will be by using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library.

```
const date = moment('2017-12-31-19-40','YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm');
console.log(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```